# Can't update anything on Store

Tags: windows-10-mobile, store, error

I got some updates on my store including the store update, but none o them seems to be updating, after clicking update in 2-3 seconds it shows error. the message is same for all:

> - **Try that again**
> - Something went wrong
> - The error code is 0x80073CFE, in case you need it.

I can download new apps and also successfully WhatsApp Beta. All the other apps like Office based apps, store, camera, mail,onenote,etc are all giving same message as mentioned above. Please help me.

My phone is 520, running on 10586.494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite common issue if you are running the Insider preview and there is a work around.

---

## Workaround 1

The workaround allows you can to bypass error code 0x80073CF9 and successfully update the applications. Do the following:

1. Update the affected apps from the Windows Store
2. Wait for the update to fail and for error code 0x80073CF9 to be
   displayed.
3. Once error code has been displayed, navigate to the Windows Store app page for the specific app that has failed to update, and update it from its page.
4. Now the app should install or update without an error code.

   ---

## Workaround 2

As mentioned in this reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/3aa5c4/build_10136_growing_list_of_app_updates_failing/),

> I had this issue too. After a Hard Reset i had around 20~23 apps to
>   update, a lot of those failed.
>
> The "Fix" i'm using when an app fails to update is:
>
> - cancel those updates when the error appears (tap into the X button), this will remove the apps from the Download list.
> - Once all the other apps update, tap "Search for updates" button.
>
> Those apps will appear and start updating again, few will fail again,
>   just repeat both steps again until all your apps update. It's tedious
>   but it worked for me. Apps like OneDrive, Skype, etc i had to
>   uninstall and install again to get them work.

---

## Solution

As stated in his [article](https://appuals.com/best-fix-error-0x80073cf9-in-windows-store-on-windows-10-mobile/) your only solution is to Hard Reset.

> Error code 0x80073CF9 can also be fixed for good, but doing so
>   requires you to perform a hard reset on your device.

---

## Reason

The reason for the problem as given in the [article](https://appuals.com/best-fix-error-0x80073cf9-in-windows-store-on-windows-10-mobile/) is as follows,

> Error code 0x80073CF9, in almost all cases, is caused by specific
>   files pertaining to the Windows Store that tend to go missing when a
>   phone is upgraded to the latest build of the Windows 10 Mobile Insider
>   Preview.

---

## Reference

1. [BEST FIX: Error 0x80073CF9 in Windows Store on Windows 10 Mobile](https://appuals.com/best-fix-error-0x80073cf9-in-windows-store-on-windows-10-mobile/)

Comment: as per you mentioned in **workaround** , am still getting the error! and as per my query, the error code is ........CFE , not ...........CF9

Comment: @RamRaj Yes, I am aware of that. Both the error are caused by same problem(missing of store files). Both of them causes same problems. So I posted so that a same solution may also apply for both of them. Updated a second workaround that is particularly for the error mentioned. According to the reddit post linked there it worked for some and didn't work for some. Updating store imediatly after a hard reset before all apps was also a workaround. Try these.

Comment: i did a hard reset, solved the problem. any idea how this issue was triggered?

Comment: @RamRaj A file corrupted (a .dll file) during the update process was said to be the reason of this error in PC. This is the reason in mobile too.